# How to handle dynamic route params using the fluxible-router

Tags: fluxible

How can I access the dynamic navParams using the fluxible-router

For instance if I have a user component and I want to set the userId prop of the component based on the route

```
// configs/routes.js
module.exports = {
    home: {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: require('../components/Home.jsx'),
        // Executed on route match
        action: require('../actions/loadHome')
    },
    user: {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/user/:id',
        handler: require('../components/User.jsx')
    }
};
```

https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-router/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md

How can I access that userId in the User.jsx component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the fluxible-router here, generated apps usually do.

Every router call includes a Payload parameter:

```
module.exports = {
    user: {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/user/:id',
        handler: require('../components/Home.jsx'),
        action: function(context, payload, done) {
            console.log( payload.toJS() );
            context.executeAction(registerCollector, payload, done);
            done();
        }
    }
};
```

More on where this parameter is created in [the docs](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-router/blob/master/docs/api/navigateAction.md). But that parameter contains all your URL-parameters as a JSON object.

**To access them you have to use the payload.toJS() function** though. Which took me quite a while to find, since it's not emphasised in the docs.

To access them directly in the Component, use the [handleRoute API](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-router/blob/master/docs/api/handleRoute.md).

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I also accessed it via `payload.get('params').get('keyword')` as well, but it looks like the payload.toJs might be easier.

Comment: How to use handleRoute api to get the parameter in component ?